# Determine force of particle along trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centrifugal-force, constrained-dynamics

**The problem:**
I have a trajectory in cartesian plane defined by points.
A particle with mass $m$ runs through this trajectory, with a defined initial velocity. At every moment, there is a force $F$ applied to the particle.
This force is constant in modulus, but can change direction.
I want to calculate, for each point, the direction of that force.

**My way of thinking:**
I try by calculating, on each point, the curvature of the trajectory defined by the radius of the circle that pass through 3 points $(p-1, p, p+1)$, thus I can calculate the maximum speed of the particle if the force is radial. 
Then, I start from the point of the trajectory where this speed is minumim, and inclinate the force to obtain the needed acceleration.
But I can't solve the problem.

Comment: What are the other forces, like gravity? If no other forces act on it, the particle travels in a straight line as per $ v^2= v_0^2 + 2 s F/m $.

Comment: Do you know calculus?

Comment: @Narasimham: the trajectory is defined, is not straight line. There is only the force "F"

Comment: @Aaron Stevens: what did you mean?

Comment: I mean, do you know calculus? It isn't a trick question :)

Comment: ok, I'm sorry I didn't know the english translation. Yes I know it, but I need a refresh

Comment: If you know $\mathbf x(t)$ then the net force is easily determined by $$\mathbf F=m\cdot\frac{\text d^2\mathbf x}{\text dt^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I post an answer, because I have limited number of characters on comments.

The acceleration is constant in modulus, the direction is variable.

The particle follow a path discretized as series of dots, and could have any shape. These dots could be connected by a spline.

In this moment I solved the problem in an "engineering way": I assume, for simplicity, that every 3 dots the path is a circle, in this way I can calculate the radius $R$ and thus the maximum speed possible in every dot (if I assume no longitudinal acceleration):

$v^2 = a R$.

I create a graph with position on x axis and this speed on y axis.
Then, I calculate the derivative of the speed $dv/dx$, and the number of time $n$ that derivative is zero.

Now, I start a loop that repeat $n$ times.

Start from the first point with $dv/dx=0$, I assume that the speed is the maximum one (no longitudinal acceleration).
Then, I impose the same speed on the next and on the previous dots.
In these dots the radius is higher, thus the centrifugal acceleration is lower, there is longitudinal acceleration and I can calculate it.
I continue in this way for every dots.

At the end of the loop, I have more than one speed on each dot: if, for example, $n=3$, on each dot I have 3 different speed.
I keep only the lower one.

In this manner, I solve the problem. I know where the particle accelerate, when brake, and how much.
But is a numerical solution. I'm looking for an analytics one.

Answer (score 0):

Let constant acceleration be  $F/m=a$

The following is valid for a circular path if $R=$ constant. However $R$ can as well be made a defined variable in  terms of any $(x,y, r, \theta)$ on the right hand side of Equation 3).

From the three given points we compute instantaneous radius of path curvature $= R$.

To convert independent variable $\theta$ to time derivatives ( dot indicates time derivative and primes, the $\theta$ derivative)

$$\quad \omega= \dot \theta \tag1 $$
$$ r' = \frac {\dot r}{\dot \theta}=\frac{\dot r}{\omega} ,\quad r^{''}=\frac{\omega \ddot r- \dot r \dot\omega }{\omega^2}, \quad \tag2 $$

Curvature in polar coordinates  from an arbitrary pole

$$ \frac{r^2+2  r' ^2 - r  r''}{(r^2 + r' ^2)^{3/2} } = 1/R \tag3$$

where after substituting from (2) we get

$$ \frac{\dot \omega^3}{\omega^2}\cdot \frac{\omega^2 r^2+ 2 \dot r^2 -\omega r \ddot r+ r \dot r \dot\omega}{(\dot\omega^2 r^2+ \dot r^2)^{3/2}} =\frac{1}{R}\tag4$$

Equilibrium of forces in polar coordinates along tangential ( Coriolis)/normal (Centripetal) directions respectively the vector magnitudes sum up to a constant acceleration $a$

$$ (2 \dot r  \omega )^2+ ( r \omega^2)^2 = a^2 \tag5 $$

Coupled OD equations $(4,5) $ can be integrated analytically (tough?) or numerically to solve for $(\omega, r )$ by an Runge-Kutta 4th order algorithm  with given initial conditions.

$$ \theta =\int \omega\,dt \tag6 $$

$(r,\theta)$ polar equation for given path is determined.

And finally the changing direction of force ( inclination to normal vector)

$$ \tan^{-1}\frac{\omega \,r}{\dot r} \tag7 $$ is also determined.

By the same procedure direction for a variable curvature 1/R path can be also computed.

Comment: The OP did not assume a constant acceleration nor circular motion.

Comment: 1) Magnitude of acceleration is given constant and  variable  .direction  calculated  2) The above *R* can be also generalized to be a defined variable as stated.